# C++ Inheritance of functions with same name

Tags: c++

I have the following class declarations:

```
class human
{
    public:
    void msg(){cout<<"I am human\n";}
};
class John:public human 
{
    public:
    void msg(){cout<<"I am a John\n";}
};
```

As it is clear the class `John` and `human` both have a function `msg()`. Clearly , the class `John` is inheriting resources from `human`. Now when I create an object of the derived class and call `msg()`:

```
John a;
a.msg();
```

The output is :

> I am John

But doesnt `John` inherit `msg()` from `human`?

Also is there a way to access `msg()` of `human` by using an object of the derived class?

***EDIT:***

Yup calling the function like so will help me

```
a.human::msg()
```

*Another question :*

Also if I modify the class like so:

```
class human
{
    protected:
    void msg(){cout<<"I am human\n";}
};
class John:public human 
{
    public:
    void msg(){cout<<"I am a John\n";}
};
```

Now how can I access the `msg()` of `human`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"But doesnt John inherit msg() from human?"*

Yes it does, but hides it with its own implementation.

> *"Also is there a way to access msg() of human?"*

Yes, you need to explicitly state the class scope (as long `human::msg()` is in public scope as it was originally asked):

```
  John a;
  a.human::msg();
 // ^^^^^^^
```

The same syntax needs to be applied if you want to access `human::msg()` from within class `John`:

```
class John : public human {
    public:
    void msg() {cout<<"I am a John\n";}
    void org_msg() { human::msg(); }
};

John a;
a.org_msg();
```

or another alternative

```
John john;
human* h = &john;
h->msg();
```